# Read json extra fields and associate with create method django rest api

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

How can I read extra content of JSON data to associate with my creation user model by sending something like this:

```
{
    "extrafieldstring": "hey_"
    "username": "test",
}
```

Here's the code for my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
          'username',
        ]

    def create (self, validated_data):
        c = extrafieldstring???+validated_data['username']
        user = User.objects.create(username=c)
        user.set_password(User.objects.make_random_password())
        user.save()
        return user
```

I don't want to include another model to do this task. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

request:

```
curl -H ' Content-Type: multipart/form-data' -POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/update_user -F extrafieldstring="hey_" -F username="test"
```

serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def create (self, validated_data):
        c = validated_data['extrafieldstring']+validated_data['username']
        ...
```

Comment: If i try to do it by raw on default DRF post option page, shows me: 
KeyError: 'client'

Comment: What abt form data?